# How can i evaluate this query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

This query give me error:Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 10
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'where'.

```
declare @date1 datetime,@date2 datetime , @COUNT INT , @countgap int, @order int
seLECT @date1='2009-05-11' , @date2 = '2009-05-12'
seLECT @countgap = 30 , @COUNT = 0, @order=23 

select VisitingCount from (
select count(page) as VisitingCount,   
    (datepart(hour,Date)*60+datepart(minute,Date))/@countgap as OrderNumber 
    from scr_SecuristLog  
    where Date between @date1 and  @date2
    GROUP BY (datepart(hour,Date)*60+datepart(minute,Date))/@countgap) where OrderNumber=@order
```

Comment: i dont understand Editing code in stackoverflow?

Answer (score 3):

Pherhaps:

```
GROUP BY (datepart(hour,Date)*60+datepart(minute,Date))/@countgap) 
HAVING OrderNumber=@order
```

or:

```
where (Date between @date1 and  @date2) AND OrderNumber=@order
GROUP BY (datepart(hour,Date)*60+datepart(minute,Date))/@countgap)
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to give your derived table a name e.g. DT1. Here I've reformatted the SQL text to my personal liking :) to make it easier to read:

```
select DT1.VisitingCount 
  from (
        select count(page) as VisitingCount,   
               (datepart(hour,Date)*60+datepart(minute,Date))/@countgap 
                  as OrderNumber 
          from scr_SecuristLog  
         where Date between @date1 and  @date2
         GROUP 
            BY (datepart(hour,Date)*60+datepart(minute,Date))/@countgap
       ) AS DT1 
 where DT1.OrderNumber=@order
```